# Lettuce only retrieving 100 results when performing scan

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

This code is returning only 100 results, even if there are tens of thousands of entries in the redis database:

```
RedisFuture<List<Object>> future = redis.dispatch(CommandType.SCAN, new ArrayOutput<String, String>(StringCodec.UTF8), new CommandArgs<String, String>(StringCodec.UTF8).add("aircraft"));

List<Object> result = Collections.emptyList();
try {
    result = future.get();
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    // TODO: Do something
}

if(result.size() > 1) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<List<String>> aircraft = (List<List<String>>) result.get(1);
    Map<String, Aircraft> retval = aircraft.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(it -> it.get(0), it -> {
        try {
            JsonNode positionJson = objectMapper.readTree(it.get(1)).get("coordinates");
            return new Aircraft(positionJson.get(0).asDouble(), positionJson.get(1).asDouble());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }));
    return retval;
} else {
    return Collections.emptyMap();
}
```